# Как узнать оставшееся дисковое пространство?

Tags: php, google-drive

Как узнать оставшееся дисковое пространство на гугл диске? Документация не помогает. Делал вот так:

```
 $service = new Google_Service_Drive($this->google);

 $about = $service->about->get();
 $vars = $about->quotaStorage()->getLimit();
```

Не помогло. Пробовал и из документации:

```
$about = $service->about->get();

print "Current user name: " . $about->getName();
print "Root folder ID: " . $about->getRootFolderId();
print "Total quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesTotal();
print "Used quota (bytes): " . $about->getQuotaBytesUsed();
```

Результата 0. Только ругается, что не хватает fields, а где, непонятно.

Comment: Мы тоже можем только гадать что у вас там не получается, и почему.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, в v3 данные не передаются избыточным путем. Вы должны специфицировать через `fields`, то, что ожидаете увидеть.

К сожалению, я не знаю, как это в PHP, но, вероятно, что-то около вот этого

```
$requestParameters = [
    'fields' => '*'
];

$about = $service->about->get($requestParameters);
```

Чтобы ваши методы корректно отработали, вероятно, достаточно иметь следующую настройку

```
'fields' => 'user(displayName),storageQuota(limit,usage)'
```